# Are edit's that translate the user's post ok?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've recently begun going through the suggested edit queue and came across this today:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19049634

The edit takes the original post (in French) and translates it to English. I'm not quite sure if this is a valid edit and if I should approve or reject. This time I skipped, but for future reference, are these types of edits acceptable?

Comment: Is the question, after translation, better?

Comment: The english is complete nonsense. The editor has just pasted it to google translate and back.

Comment: **Don't translate it; don't approve edits that translate it.**  You have no way of validating the accuracy of the translation.  More details in the dupe.

Comment: @BDL: but reading the posts of that wanna-be editor, I suspect that's actually a good thing.

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372777/how-to-deal-with-translated-posts