# How to deal with translated posts?

Tags: support, languages, english

I know I should not translate posts into English. I also know that I should reject edits that translates posts.

But what should I do when a 2k-user has made the edit? Rollback? Flag?

> This question is not answered in the supposed dup [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) since this question is specifically about non-English content. My question is specifically about English content that was non-English *before* translation. None of the answers answers my question.
>
> And neither is it in this: [Translating posts in edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325568/translating-posts-in-edits) which is about how to handle translated posts in the suggested edit review queue. My question is about how to handle posts that are past this stage.  None of the answers answers my question.

Comment: Just post a comment so that answerers know that the OP is unlikely to understand any answers.  Something like "Note: original question translated from Swahili, OP does not speak English".

Comment: Related: [Translating posts in edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325568/7795130)

Comment: @Lino Related but not a duplicate of that: this question asks how to proceed when the accepted answer to that other question was ignored.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The proposed duplicate is about questions written in other languages. This question asks what we should do if a user has already translated them. The answers on the proposed duplicate do not answer this.

Comment: Be rational: close your eyes. You closed it already as you blindly adapted an obviously contraproductive, destructive rule, at least close when you should apply it.

Comment: @peterh If you think the rule of not translating is a bad one... go ahead and make an MSO question to challenge it. The rationale behind not translating questions, is that the OP would not understand the feedback. If you can find evidence that this rationale doesn't hold, you could get a rule change.

Comment: @S.L.Barth In the case of such "rules" I long gave up to even try to find a "rationale". I see only *behaviors*. These are very simple: if there is *any* question, thing to decide, then the majority votes to close, down, del, suspend, flag. That it s a very consequent behavior. Why is it so? I have many ideas, but none if them could I say for sure.

Comment: I'd think that the significance of the translation has to be taken into account. For example, if it's only a partial edit because it's obvious that the OP didn't know the appropriate word.

Answer (score 22):

*Definitely* flag the post as a bad edit and get it to a moderator's attention.  A 2K+ rep user making that kind of edit should genuinely know better than to translate a post on the OP's behalf.

I'd advise some level of caution when rolling the post back.  Rolling back the question when there are active answers on it may make for a confusing circumstance.  Do what you believe is practical here; it may be safest to simply flag and walk away.

Comment: While I agree that a 2k user (or more relevant: a user with edit privileges) should know better, I don't agree that this user necessarily should be blamed. I know it I should not translate posts now, but I did not until I had around 4k. To be honest, I did not know until today about the [SO FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/6699433)

Comment: @klutt Just learned about the SO FAQ you linked to (11k at the time of writing).

Comment: My personal preference, rather than immediately flagging to report the edit, is to first try to inform the editor of the policies by leaving them a comment linking to [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673). If providing them with that information doesn't get them to stop translating posts, then I'll flag for a moderator. In my experience *most* people are happy to comply, once they know that they are not supposed to edit in translations.

Comment: A comment as simple as `@[user who edited] So that you know, the consensus is that we should *not* translate posts for users. For more information, please see: [How do I deal with non-English content?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680)` is usually effective. Someone who has successfully edited the post is pingable from a comment, but their name won't autocomplete, so you have to enter their username manually.

Comment: @Makyen:  I'm not entirely sold on that methodology.  A person who has 2K+ reputation should well know by now that the rule on the site is that this is an English-only site.  Any further concerns on if that extended to translations should've been elaborated on when they searched on the matter.  My gut tells me that a user who's at that rep level genuinely should've been around for a while and genuinely *should* know better.  While you and Abbas have raised good points, I don't see comments as an effective vehicle of communication for correcting this sort of behavior.

Comment: @Makoto I understand that POV, and I agree that, in an ideal world, they *should* know it by that point. Unfortunately, that type of information is not easily discoverable. The discoverability of a large part of the information that forms the consensus under which SO/SE operates is an issue which we, unfortunately, have to deal with. My experience is that only a *very* few users don't respond to being pointed at a Meta that discusses the policy/consensus (i.e. very few don't change their behavior). After all, what do you expect a moderator to do for a first offense? Suspend the user?

Comment: @Makyen:  I'm not sure it's pertinent for me to *care*....abuse of the editing feature has always been in the moderator's wheelhouse, and it's up to that specific moderator to decide what the appropriate next steps should be.  I'm trying to define a philosophy in which my responsibilities as a power user are clearly delineated from a moderator's responsibilities, and I believe user correction is one of those aspects.

Comment: Just because the user has enough rep for editing does not mean they follow all the latest developments, minor rules and meta discussions. I think leaving a comment to let the user know about a rule is perfectly fine. Another option could be to catch them in the chat, but this may be difficult if they don’t frequent it.

Comment: @Makoto: I think the main benefit of Makyen's approach is that it assumes good faith. Give the editor the benefit of the doubt by gently reminding them, and if they prove pig-headed *then* alert the moderators to handle the issue. Of course, if you do not wish your own name to be associated with the issue (shy, fear retaliation, etc...), then just signaling the moderators is fine too.

Comment: FWIW I'm at 2394 and never had come across this issue before.

Comment: At 1141 here and if it weren't for the dumb luck of stumbling here by accident, I wouldn't have known before I reached 2k.

Comment: @Makoto As per Yvette's [revision comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/297680/14) to the "How do I deal with non-English content?" FAQ post today, it seems moderators have come to a decision that translating is now an acceptable course of action. Because of that, you may want to change your suggestion in this answer or put a notice to mark the change in the guidelines because flagging for moderator attention doesn't seem to be the right course of action anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Considering the often discussed and lamented scarcity of good questions, maybe it's actually worth evaluating the quality of the question after translation. (I'm referring to questions rather than answers. I don't remember seeing many non-English answers, and I don't really know if that's something that happens as frequently.) I generally agree with the reasoning behind the rule about not translating questions, that the OP won't understand the answers/comments, and won't be able to respond, but I wonder if strict application of this rule could counterproductively prioritize the person over the question in some rare cases.

Theoretically, the main purpose of the Q&A is not just for the OP, but for anyone to find who may have the same question, and if the translated version of the post is a clear and useful question that can be reasonably answered without any help from the OP, then it seems like a shame to prevent it from being answered just because the one person who happened to ask it may not understand the answers. Many people who do speak English and ask their questions in English don't understand the answers they get either, and we don't necessarily close those. We don't even discourage people from answering questions where the OP account doesn't exist any more, and it's certainly unlikely to get any feedback from the OP there.

On the other hand, it seems like most non-English questions usually *do* need other improvement and clarification from the OP as well, so the "don't translate" rule makes perfect sense in most cases. It seems safe to assume that someone who doesn't know that they're supposed to ask in English hasn't read the help about how to ask, and is probably missing some other important question quality concepts as well. I think even people who are in favor of translating questions would agree that translating a question when the English version sucks anyway isn't worthwhile.

But if somehow, the only thing wrong with the question is that it isn't in English and it's a great question after being translated, maybe we could allow for an occasional exception to "don't translate". Just a thought.

Comment: How can you trust the translation?  (Thus, the basis of "great question" is thrown into doubt.)  How can you be assured that the OP will come back to engage with their question if it's unclear?

Comment: @Makoto I'm not proposing that an unclear question could be worthy of an exception. I was thinking of a scenario where a person who spoke the other language knew the answer to the question and translated it properly, not one of the various instances of someone doing a google translate copy/paste. I don't know, maybe it's an unlikely enough scenario that I shouldn't have bothered mentioning it.

Comment: It *happens*, but it's very much the case of whether or not we can truly trust or put faith into the reliability of the translation.  As lackadaisical as it sounds, it's simpler to trust *no* translation.

Comment: @Makoto fair enough. I only speak English, so I'd have to assume good intentions and competence of the person doing the translating. I suppose that's a bit naive.

Comment: If you find the question good enough, and you understand the question completely and can reproduce the problems on your own, then you have the perfectly valid option of reposting the question as if it was your own.

Comment: I once posted a question in French, and someone was nice enough to translate it. It has now a score of +2 with an accepted answer of +5 so it's arguably reasonably useful content now. I still don't get how i could post it in French (that wasn't even my first post here)... Probably high tiredness and unforgivable casualness... Anyway, i do feel my translator made the right thing, and it made me wanting to pay more attention and help improving other's posts as mine had the chance to be.
So, I do agree with you.

Comment: Until I read Vincent's comment above I was going to comment "nice theory, but that never happens in practice". I would still regard it as highly unusual, enough to not be a significant factor in this discussion; but sure, a bit of context-sensitivity before applying the #1 rule makes sense.

Comment: No. ___Never___ translate posts. The OP will likely not be able to understand comments / answers. Close-vote as "unclear". It's the OP's responsibility to make the question answerable.

Comment: @Cerbrus **Yes, translate the posts and fix them**, so is it constructive and positive. That "rule" is a school example of the unreasonable hostility, unwelcomingness and irrational destructivity.

Comment: @peterh don't give me that "welcoming" spiel. There's nothing welcoming about answering a question in a language the OP ___doesn't understand___. That's the reason we remove non-english content instead of translating it.