# Add translation guidelines to the edit privilege page

Tags: feature-request, edits, privileges, languages, english

Today I saw [How to deal with translated posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372777/how-to-deal-with-translated-posts) and I thought that there must be something about this in the [Edit Questions And Answers privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) but to my dismay there was nothing in there.  The general consensus I have seen from moderators and users is one should not edit a translation in.

Could we add to the page a guideline that translations should not be done?

Comment: _"unless you actually speak the language yourself."_ Wait what? No. Never translate a post. Just close it as "unclear". The OP will not be able to respond to comments. It's unlikely the OP will understand any answer...

Comment: @Cerbrus I guess I was remembering wrong.  I've update the request

Comment: Thanks. Keep in mind that, in the end, it's the OP's responsibility to make their question answerable. If they don't know English, then SO is not the site for them...

Comment: There should be a new page (maybe under https://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation?) which has sections for how to edit, how to review, etc. I've never understood why things like that are under Privileges anyway. The privilege page should just tell you what it grants you, with a link to another place that describe what we expect for those exercising the privilege.

Answer (score 4):

The privileges page isn't designed to be a lengthy tutorial on exactly how editing works, describing all of the rules and guidelines and practices to consider.  It's just a very basic, high level overview of what the feature is, so someone who isn't familiar with editing *at all* on the site can have an introduction to the topic.  We don't want to be editing the page with all sorts of very fringe guidance on editing that comes up fairly rarely.

Comment: True, but what is 1 more line telling users not to translate posts, on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)?

Comment: @Cerbrus Then someone else will want to add a line for some other edge case that comes up super rarely, and then another, and then pretty soon it's three pages long and no one ever reads it.  That's not the place for that information.